# How react knows that this component will be going to be unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         delete: false,
      };
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>User List</h1>
            <button onClick={() => this.setState({ delete: true })}>
               Delete Users
            </button>
            {this.state.delete ? null : <User />}
         </div>
      );
   }
}

class User extends React.Component {
   componentWillUnmount() {
      alert('Deleted User successfully');
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h3>Username: Rahul</h3>
            <h3>Email: rbbansal558@gmail.com</h3>
         </div>
      );
   }
}
export default App;
```

In this code example, there are two classes, one is an App and another one is a User class. So, how is React going to know that the User class is going to be unmounted?

Comment: What do you mean? React is the thing that's managing _all_ of your components, how would it _not_ know it was about to do that?

Comment: I mean like, When componentWillUnmount() method is going to call, or when component is going to be unmounted, How react is going to know?

Comment: It's going to know because _it's what's calling it_, React is the thing that manages the lifecycle and asks the browser to update the real DOM accordingly. It knows because App just returned a null where it previously returned a User, because that's what your logic says.

Comment: You said, "It knows because App jus returned a null where it previously returned a User", But, My question was how react is going to know that the User component is going to destroy and call componetDidMount().

Comment: If you have a simple `if-else` statement that shows/hides an element, and you want to call a function before it is shown/hidden, you can add a call into the `if` and the `else` before your show/hide to do just that, because you are the one showing/hiding it. In this case, React is the one mounting/unmounting (equivalent to showing/hiding in our simplified example), so it knows exactly when it will mount/unmount a component.

Comment: It knows because **you asked it** to do that. Your components are instructions to React about what you want it to render, that's the whole point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React is what unmounts the component and since react manages the lifecycle of all of its components, well it knows that it is unmounting the component, so it calls componentWillUnmount. Its all in the documentation. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html